# Convert multiple HTML files to PDF with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, pdf, converters, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

I tried to follow a tutorial and programmed something via Python to convert an HTML file to PDF.
In my case "sample.html".

```
import pdfkit

#Define path to wkhtmltopdf.exe
path_to_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkthmltopdf.exe'

#Define path to HTML file
path_to_file = 'sample.html'

#Point pdfkit configuration to wkhtml.exe
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf = path_to_wkhtmltopdf)

#Convert HTML file to PDF
pdfkit.from_file(path_to_file, output_path = 'sample.pdf', configuration = config)
```

But now I have a folder with many HTML files and it would be too much work to do it for each file individually. What part of the code would I need to change to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Python or PDFkit to run WkHTMLtoX, but they do provide a wrapper to files and settings. However if you know the switches to get the desired layout, you can use them in a batch file, running from a working folder.

Here are two ways of converting HTML to PDF (there are many others) and each has their merits. I include the batch file for you to place in a test set folder (and or sub folders) you will need to edit the exe folder names and add any switches desired.

[image]

htm2pdf.cmd

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM Define path to wkhtmltopdf.exe
set "wkhtm2x=C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"

REM Define path to MSEdge.exe this should not need changing here
set "msedge=%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"

REM switch to working folder
cd /d "%~dp0"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%F in (`dir /s /b "*.htm*"`) do (

echo running wkhtmltox
"%wkhtm2x%" "%%F" "%%~dpnF-wkhm2.pdf"

echo running edge htm2pdf
"%msedge%" --headless --print-to-pdf="%%~dpnF-edge2.pdf" "%%F"
 )
```

Copy and paste above lines in plain text as a batch file. For example, named as htm2pdf.cmd (can be any.cmd or any.bat). Then copy to a test folder, with say a dozen good example.htm or .html. Also, include some in sub directories too. Then simply double click the file to run it.

Each input file should produce two very basic outputs for your comparison.

To change options for MS Edge like remove print top and tail you need to add extra switches before "%%F". such as `--headless --no-pdf-header-footer`

For wkhtmltox you will likely need extra switches before "%%F" in that line but they will be related to permissions & scaling etc. However you need to compare what python might use.

When choosing options for wkhtmltox there are too many to list here but on a private system one that is often needed is `--enable-local-file-access`. Other ones may be to control margins or autoscale such as `--disable-smart-shrinking`

Comment: Should I insert the lines one after the other into the cmd input here?

Answer (score -1):

I add sample code below.

```
import os
import pdfkit

path_to_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
html_folder_path = r'path/to/html/files'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_to_wkhtmltopdf)
html_files = [file for file in os.listdir(html_folder_path) if file.endswith('.html')]

for html_file in html_files:
    input_html_path = os.path.join(html_folder_path, html_file)
    output_pdf_path = os.path.join(html_folder_path, f'{os.path.splitext(html_file)[0]}.pdf')

    pdfkit.from_file(input_html_path, output_path=output_pdf_path, configuration=config)

print("Conversion completed.")
```

Comment: Thank you!
Unfortunately, I get the following error: "Import "pdfkit" could not be resolved". Pdfkit is actually installed.